# groupby in pandas with function that must keep state

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'b': [  1,   2,   4,   1,   2,   3,   4]})
```

I want a function that would output the following dataframe definition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [  'A',   'A',   'A',   'B',   'B',   'B',   'B'],
                   'b': [    1,     2,     4,     1,     2,     3,     4],
                   'c': ['A_0', 'A_0', 'A_1', 'B_0', 'B_0', 'B_0', 'B_0']})
```

The logic is that given for each value of 'a' (each group), I create a value 'c' which could be described as a "continuous" series of 'b' values.

So far, my code is the following:

```
def detection(dataset):
    def detect(series, avalue):
        _id = 0
        start = True
        visits = []
        prev_ = None
        for h in series:
            if start:
                start = False
                prev_ = h
            else:
                if h - prev_ > 1:
                    _id += 1
                prev_ = h
            visits.append(f"{avalue}_{_id}")
        return visits

    res = []
    gb = dataset.groupby("a")
    for avalue in gb.groups:
        dd = gb.get_group(avalue)
        dd["VISIT_ID"] = detect(dd["b"], avalue)
        res.append(dd)
    return pd.concat(res, axis=0)
```

The good is, it works perfectly !!
The bad: it is extremely slow on a large dataset (7 millions of entries, 250k of different 'a' values.

Is there something better to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the numeric part of column c using groupby and concat values

```
df['c'] = df.groupby('a').b.apply(lambda x: (x.diff() > 1).cumsum())
df['c'] = df['a'] + '_' + df['c'].astype(str)


    a   b   c
0   A   1   A_0
1   A   2   A_0
2   A   4   A_1
3   B   1   B_0
4   B   2   B_0
5   B   3   B_0
6   B   4   B_0
```

Comment: Woosh 4x speed improvement and a waay shorter solution!